# Adding fetched resources to knownresources based on API call

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm attempting to add resources based on an API call. I can add knownResources without issues, I can also add fetchedResources on their own - however I cannot combine the two.

The docs show how you can display resources based on permissions queried from the API, but it doesn't detail how to add resources dynamically if they are not declared:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#declaring-resources-at-runtime

If the two are combined (as below) the CoreAdminRouter throws an error:
**TypeError: child.props is undefined**

Any ideas on how to resolve are appreciated! The code is below:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import { restClient } from 'ra-data-feathers';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import feathersClient from './feathersClient'; 
import englishMessages from 'ra-language-english';

// import customRoutes from './customRoutes';
import { createBrowserHistory as createHistory } from 'history';

import createRealtimeSaga from "./createRealtimeSaga";

import { Contacts } from './services/contacts';
import { Group, GroupMember } from './services/groups';
import { Albums, Photos, PublicPhotosList } from './services/photos';



import UserIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import GroupIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Group';
import GroupIcon from '@material-ui/icons/GroupWork';
import StarIcon from '@material-ui/icons/StarRate';
import FolderSpecialIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FolderSpecial';


const authClientOptions = {
    storageKey: 'feathers-jwt',
    authenticate: { strategy: 'local' }
};

const history = createHistory();

const options = {
    usePatch: false, // Use PATCH instead of PUT for UPDATE requests. Optional.
    contacts: { // Options for individual resources can be set by adding an object with the same name. Optional.
        id: 'ContactId' // If this specific table uses an id field other than 'id'. Optional.
    },
    group: { // Options for individual resources can be set by adding an object with the same name. Optional.
        id: 'GroupId' // If this specific table uses an id field other than 'id'. Optional.
    },
    groupmember: { // Options for individual resources can be set by adding an object with the same name. Optional.
        id: 'GroupMemberID' // If this specific table uses an id field other than 'id'. Optional.
    },
    albums: { // Options for individual resources can be set by adding an object with the same name. Optional.
        id: 'AlbumId' // If this specific table uses an id field other than 'id'. Optional.
    },
    photos: { // Options for individual resources can be set by adding an object with the same name. Optional.
        id: 'PhotoId' // If this specific table uses an id field other than 'id'. Optional.
    }, 
    "photos/albums/1/": { // Options for individual resources can be set by adding an object with the same name. Optional.
        id: 'AlbumId' // If this specific table uses an id field other than 'id'. Optional.
    },
    "photos/albums/2/": { // Options for individual resources can be set by adding an object with the same name. Optional.
        id: 'AlbumId' // If this specific table uses an id field other than 'id'. Optional.
    },


}


const dataProvider = restClient(feathersClient, options)

const realTimeSaga = createRealtimeSaga(dataProvider);

const messages = {
    en: englishMessages,
}
const i18nProvider = locale => messages[locale];

const knownResources = [

    <Resource name="contacts" list={ContactsList} show={ContactsShow}  icon={UserIcon} />,
    <Resource name="group"  list={GroupList} show={GroupShow} icon={GroupIcon}/>,
    <Resource name="groupmember"  list={GroupMemberList} show={GroupMemberShow} icon={GroupIcon}/>,
    <Resource name="albums"  list={AlbumList} show={AlbumsShow} icon={GroupIcon}/>,
    <Resource name="photos"  list={PhotoList} show={PhotosShow} icon={GroupIcon}/>,

    //******************************************************************
    //**These resources need to be dynamically Added based on API Call**
    //******************************************************************
    // <Resource name="photos/albums/1/" list={PublicPhotosList} icon={StarIcon}/>,
    // <Resource name="photos/albums/2/" list={PublicPhotosList} icon={StarIcon}/>,
    // <Resource name="photos/albums/3/" list={PublicPhotosList} icon={StarIcon}/>,
    // etc.


];


// const fetchResources = permissions =>
//     fetch('https://myapi/resources', {
//         method: 'POST',
//         headers: {
//             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
//         },
//         body: JSON.stringify(permissions),
//     })
//     .then(response => response.json())
//     .then(json => knownResources.filter(resource => json.resources.includes(resource.props.name)));

const fetchResources = () => 
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/hasphotos/true?$limit=10')
    .then(function(response){return response.json()})
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    .then(function(schemas){
        var filtered = schemas.data
        // console.log(schema.data)
        return filtered.map((schema, index)=>{
            let name = 'photos/album/'+schema.AlbumId

            options[name] = {
                    id: 'AlbumId'
            }

            var resource;

            if(schema.Results.length!==0){

                resource = <Resource  
                name={'photos/albums/'+schema.AlbumId}
                list={PublicPhotosList}
                options = {{
                    label:schema.AlbumName
                }}/>;


                knownResources.push(resource);
                console.log(knownResources)
            }
            return knownResources
        })
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))


const App = () => (
    <Admin 
        // authProvider={authClient(feathersClient, authClientOptions)}
        restClient={restClient(feathersClient, options)}
        dataProvider={restClient(feathersClient, options)}
        customSagas={[realTimeSaga]}
        locale="en"
        i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
        // customRoutes={customRoutes}
        history={history}
        // theme={theme} 
    >
         //{knownResources}
        {fetchResources} 
    </Admin>

);

export default App;
```

Comment: what's `PublicPhotosList`? is it defined?

Comment: Good catch, I didn't import the resource as it's an example, I'll edit it to be more accurate.

It would be another declared import ie.
import { Albums, Photos, **PublicPhotosList** } from './services/photos';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be caused by where the return statement was placed. This works - it fetches the data, then creates resources based on what is returned.

```
const fetchResources = async ( ) => {


let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/hasphotos/true?$limit=10');
let schemas = await response.json();

var filtered = schemas.data.filter(a=>a.Results.length);

filtered.map(schema => {
    let name = 'photos/album/'+schema.AlbumId


    var resource = <Resource
    key='AlbumId'
    name={'photos/album/'+schema.AlbumId}
    list={PublicPhotosList}
    options = {{
        label:schema.Album
    }}
/>;
    options[name] = {
        id: 'AlbumId'
}
    knownResources.push(resource)
    return;

    }
); 

 console.log(knownResources)
 return knownResources;
};
```